# Calculating the determinant of a matrix

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a square matrix using row operations.
I ran into this code but I do not really understand how it works.

What do `subi` and `subj` do? Does it use row operations?

What is the logic behind this code?

```
int c, subi, i, j, subj;

double submat[10][10],d=0;

if (n == 2) {
    return((mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]));
}
else {
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        subi = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            subj = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j == c)
                    continue;
                submat[subi][subj] = mat[i][j];
                subj++;
            }
            subi++;
        }
        d = d + (pow(-1, c)*mat[0][c] * determinant(n - 1, submat));
    }
}
return d;
```

Comment: You missing the function signature which looks something like `double determinant(int n, double mat[10][10])`

Comment: Here is an example of [Determinant of a Matrix](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/determinant-of-a-matrix/) explained pretty nice.  submat is a temporary matrix with row as subi and column as subj.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function using [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) to calculate the determinant whose base case is a 2 by 2 matrix.

However, it does not seem to be a good program to me for:

1. what if the input is a 1 by 1 matrix
2. submat is limited by size of 10 by 10
3. submat is a waste of memory
4. When matrix is large, it is better to use [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

The function, which looks like:

```
double determinant(int n, double mat[10][10]);
```

recursively goes through rows and calls itself on the submatrices for that row and the first column return a value for all  by  matrices.  The recursion ends for 2 by 2 matrices.